# How to make customizable form using php jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms

I'm implementing a registration form with 10-15 fields. I need to develop it in such a form like admin has rights to enable or disable fields which he wants to show user. In short form, If admin wants user to enable only 7 fields among 10., admin needs to check the fields and on clicking save settings, he want to show that customized form to user for registration. I`m currently using table format inside a form, so if user wants to remove a field, he can check the table row, so it will be disbaled.

here is the sample code

```
<table width="400" style="width:500px" border="1" align="center" id="reg_form" class="tables_section" >



            <tr>
                <td width="221"><strong>Full Name</strong></td>
                <td width="163"><span id="sprytextfield1"><input type="checkbox" name="c1" value="" checked /><input type="text" name="fname" class="alphaonly" id="fname"  maxlength="20" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><strong>Username</strong></td>
                <td><span id="sprytextfield4">
                <label for="username"></label>
                <input type="checkbox" value="" checked />
                <input type="text" name="username" class="alphaonly" id="user_id" class="user_name" ="*" maxlength="20" /><br/>
                <span class="check"></span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><strong>Email</strong></td>
                <td><span id="sprytextfield4">
                <label for="email"></label>
                <input type="checkbox" checked id="emailcheck" /><input type="email" name="email" id="email"  maxlength="40" />
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><strong>Birthday</strong></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" value="" checked /><input type="text" name="birthday" id="birthday"  readonly />

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><strong>Date of Join</strong></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" value="" checked /><input type="text" name="doj" id="doj"  readonly />

                </td>
            </tr>
</table>


<script>

    $('#savesettings').click(function(){
        if ($('table tr td checkbox').attr("checked")) {
            $('table tr').show();
        }
        else {
            $('table tr').hide();
        }
        /*});.on("click", function() {*/

    });
    $('#editsettings').on("click", function(){
        $('table tr').show();
        });






</script>
```

Comment: What is the problem that you are facing?

Comment: Do you mean: select the "checkbox", then the whole row will be disabled?

Comment: first u have to create code for admin to handle textfield front side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group your optional html form elements with DIV TAG or SPAN TAG. If admin wants to disable to hide the optional html elements use **$("DIV TAG/SPAN TAG ID/NAME").hide();** When page is loading.

Else, what are all the elements wants to hide, use those elements name or id to hide or disable.

And make sure you columns will accept null value before saving into DB.

Comment: Thank you Kumar. But I need to made this changes(I mean select the fields) in settings.php file and saved form should be loaded to registration.php.... can you tell me how to load it..